# Does the Android Application Context ever get destroyed?

Tags: android, android-context

I use my Android app's application Context as a storage area for "current state" information for my app.

I'm finding that in the field, there are cases when this information goes away on some people's devices causing various NullPointerExceptions since I expect the data to be there when the app resumes and starts rebuilding the necessary activities.

This usually happens when the user hits "Home", does something else, then eventually wanders back into the app - it attempts to go back to where it was before, but the application Context has mysteriously lost all its previously-saved state information (in my case, a few integers and a few Strings).

I know this is a very vague question, but are there any cases (other than the user using "back" to back completely out of the application) where the application Context gets completely destroyed even though the application is not terminated?

Is there a better way to maintain persistent state information?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible for the Application to be killed and restarted if the user leaves the application for a while.  You might want to read this section on [processes and lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#proclife).

You should find an appropriate place to save state to a persistent store.  If its just a few integers and strings, it should be pretty simple to save them to shared preferences as they change. See [data storage - shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: I figured as much.  Is there anything specific that I can do to *force* this situation (My Application being killed) so I can reproduce it?  It apparently happens quite a bit in the field, but I have *never* been able to reproduce it on my Nexus One locally.  In this situation is onTerminate() then called on the Application process?

Comment: @user435210 1. Look at the page with the application lifecycles - it explains nearly everything you need to know in order to manage the lifecycle of your application. 2. You can kill your application by using going in `Settings/Applications/Manage Applications/YourApp` - or by using any of a number of apps downloadable on the Android market.

Comment: If you want to reproduce it in a "friendly" way (not force kill), I would hit home, then start up every app you can find on your system so that Android is forced to close yours.  As it notes in the documentation, onTerminate may be called, but this is not a guarantee.  If, for example, your app is closed by a kill all apps application, it most likely won't be called.

Comment: @user435210: `onTerminate()` is never called, despite being in the documentation. Hence, you can simulate this effect by terminating the application process (e.g., on the emulator, use DDMS).

Comment: to kill your application process, use DDMS like commonsware said.  the DDMS tool can be accessed via the DDMS Eclipse perspective, or by running DDMS directly(found in your `android-sdk` directory under `tools`. select your application and click the `STOP` icon(stopsign).  your application should be debuggable(as set in your manifest), or it might not show up in the DDMS application list

Comment: On android 4.0 onwards, you can replicate this by going to Settings -> Developer Options -> Don't keep activities. Pressing home on your app will destroy it