# Android save Application Context

Tags: android

i am using application context for saving data, and it work fine for me ,but the problem comes,when i press home button and take some other application  and return to my application after a long time my app fail, no data in application context, how can i save the application context

Comment: Besides the shared preferences mechanics other guys have recommended, I think that it is not bad to look at the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html, the part for application lifecycle, there is wonderful picture there.

Comment: i know sharedprefrance is good method but i have large data that contain custom object also,so using it difficult for me, so am looking for anyway to save the application context directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136154/does-the-android-application-context-ever-get-destroyed) should help you. You could store the application context in shared preferences. When resuming an activity, first test if application context is empty and if it is, then load data from shared preferences.

Answer (score 2):

This is only logical. Apps can be closed by the device on low memory.

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). I suggest [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) since it is easy and just works.